# How to untie a Gordian Knot?

Tags: achievements, vvvvvv

[image]

It appears that to get to the shiny trinket, I'll have to untie that Gordian knot, but I don't have any idea about how I could achieve that.

Any clues?

Comment: According to legend the Gordian knot was untied by Alexander the Great by cutting it in half, although I am unsure if this applies to the game. I see no reason to call it that if it was not a hint of sorts. The moral of the story was to do with thinking laterally and not overlooking obvious solutions which may apply more than simply the cutting it part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way is pretty straight forward:

[image: Untieing the knot]

The tricky part is to get from the lower left to the lower right spawn point on the "Gordian Knot" screen, but with the right timing you can just press `right` on lower left span point and run through over the moving platforms onto the right ledge.

On the way back you have to pass that place again, and then you can't just run through. You have to stand on the edge of the moving panel where the spikes can't hit you and jump to the ledge at just the right moment.

Comment: Those platforms move then?

Comment: @Ronan: Yes, they move up and down, and will crush you into those spikes there if you aren't careful.

Comment: Oh. I really thought there was no way you could move through that area in that direction, but I must be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out  there is another way. With frame perfect timing you can actually go there straight from the Gordian Knot room without passing through Backsliders first.

See 5:55 in this youtube video:

Comment: This method is only for advanced players, the video by @FieryVolcano is great tho!